# VS 2010 Add-In: How to get current TFS project collection

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, visual-studio-addins

I'm about to write a Visual Studio Add-In (target environment: VS2010) that should enable the user to perform some work item related tasks. 
How can I get the TFS project that is currently active in Team Explorer? Can I subscribe to an event that informs me when the current project collection is changed?

Thanks,

Markus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a standard VS add-in project:

When the add-in is connected, the DTE-object is provided and stored in the variable `_applicationObject`. The method `GetObject` can be used to retrieve the current TFS connection data (project collection url, project name):

```
TeamFoundationServerExt tfsConn = _applicationObject.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt") as TeamFoundationServerExt;
```

In order to use the `TeamFoundationServerExt` class, a reference to the assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation is required. It is located in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll.

Comment: how get the project collection ?? sample ?